# Can we measure the distance between and AR marker and camera?

Tags: unity, camera, augmented-reality

I'm in the middle of developing a game in Augmented Reality using Unity and ARToolkit plugin. I wanted to measure the approximate distance between the AR marker and the position of camera.
Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if AR marker have Transform Component attached, then you can measure the distance.

```
  public Transform ARMarker;   //attach ar marker gameObject here
  float dist;
  void calDistance(){
  dist=Vector3.Distance(ARMarker.position,transform.position);
  Debug.Log("Distance is:"+dist);
  }
```

Attach this script to Camera.